# Probability involving DNA sequence.

Tags: probability

Question:

Suppose $P(A)=p_A, P(C)=p_C, P(T)=p_T, P(G)=p_G$. If a DNA sequence of length 1000 is observed, how can you estimate $P(A), P(C), P(T), P(G)$? What assumptions are you making? Suggest a heuristic method to assess if this sequence was generated randomly. Letters in the sequence are independent.

My attempt:

We find expected numbers using $1000P(A), 1000P(C), 1000P(T), 1000P(G)$. We used assumptions behind the Law of Large Numbers.

I am having trouble understanding and doing the last question. What is a "heuristic" method and what is this question looking for? Thank you.

Comment: You've got it backwards. You don't know P(A)..P(G) to start with, you know the actual values and you're trying to guess the probabilities. And a heuristic is a method that usually gets you an answer that is close enough, but doesn't necessarily perform perfectly in every situation.

Comment: I thought double-stranded DNA had AT and CG pairs.  Would this affect the answer?

Comment: Thank you genisage. I forgot to add one given information. The probabilities of P(A)...P(G) were actually given.

Comment: Henry, I think the question is just about the sequence of a single strand.

Comment: But now it makes even less sense. If you know $p_A$ etc, why do you want to estimate them?

Comment: Tony. I too thought the question is somewhat confusing. I'm assuming it is just asking for the expected number of each DNA base.